# Size of Google Docs entry

Tags: google-docs, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-api

Google Docs has a quotaBytesUsed method but it doesn't account for native files.  Is there any other attribute that references the size of an entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs native files don't use your storage quota so their size is not returned

Comment: Don't you like the fact that they use 0 bytes of your account?

Comment: Yes that is nice.  I'd also like to get the file size for display purposes.